# CM Redis Seesion Backend Cache on Community Edition

Tags: magento, caching, redis, magento-1.9

I am getting below error while enabling CM Redis Session Bakend cache.

> Fatal error : Call to a member function getLocaleCode() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/model/Translate.php on line 347.

**Magento Community Edition  1.9.2.1**

This seems to be working for session storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to enable the Redis backend cache, Redis session storage or both? Did you properly do the configuration (need to use the different db for each)?
Did you try to flush magento cache storage? Take a look into [this blog post](http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/) it is a good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it is working for backend cache.  I have changed different db for Redis Session Storage and Redis Backend Cache.  Have installed two redis instance of REDIS.So , flushing a Cache won't affect the other Session storage REDIS Server.  Hope this is the  right way to follow